# Force community detection in graph to two communities

Tags: r, igraph

I am doing a coalition analysis on Igraph and I would like to find a way to force the detection of communities to only two. I have tried to achieve this using fastgreedy community detection and walktrap community algorithms with no success. Is this possible to do?

Comment: If this is a question specifically about the code needed to do it, we'd need to see a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862). If it's about the stats methods behind it (like is it mathematically possible), it should get moved to [stats.se]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Next time when you say you have tried something, please show what you have done exactly.

Answer (score 1):

With community detection methods that return a hierarchical structure (dendrogram), you can use the `cut_at` function to get as many communities as you want.  This is possible with both `walktrap` and `fast_greedy`.

```
cl <- cluster_walktrap(graph)
cut_at(cl, 2)
```

Please check the documentation at https://igraph.org/r/doc/communities.html